# Change learning rate in Keras once loss stop decreasing

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm new to deep learning.

I have build a small architecture and compiling it using Adam optimizer as shown below:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss="mse")
#Train it by providing training images

model.fit(x, x, epochs=10, batch_size=16)
```

Now i'm aware of all type of decay where I can change learning rate at some epoch, but is there a way where I can change my learning rate automatically once my loss stop decreasing.

PS: It might be silly ques but please don't be harsh on me as I'm new!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Callbacks API in Keras.

It provides the following classes in `keras.callbacks` to alter learning rate on each epoch:

**1.** `LearningRateScheduler`

You can create your own learning rate schedule as a function of epoch.
Then pass the callback object to the `callbacks` argument to the `fit` method in a list.

For example, say your callback object is called `lr_callback`, then you would use:
`model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=10, callbacks=[lr_callback]`

Refer: [keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/learning_rate_scheduler/)

**2.** `ReduceLROnPlateau`

This reduces the learning rate once your learning rate stops decreasing by `min_delta` amount. You can also set the `patience` and other useful parameters.

You can pass the callback to the `fit` method in the same way as done above.

Refer: [keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/)

The usage for both the callbacks is detailed quite well in the docs, which I have linked above already.

Alternatively, you could define your own callback to schedule the learning rate, if the above do not satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As you use the Adam optimizer, the learning rate is automatically adjusted depending on the gradient. So the more the gradient reaches a global minimum, the smaller the learning rate gets, so it does not "jump" over the global minimum. I am not sure, what you want to achieve, but the learning_rate you define in `Adam()` is just a start learning rate.

For more information on Adam and optimizers, I recommend the [book](https://books.google.de/books?redir_esc=y&hl=de&id=bRpYDgAAQBAJ&q=adam%20optimizer#v=snippet&q=adam%20optimizer&f=false) hands-on machine learning of Aurélien Géron